# Style columns in CGridView based on data in yii

Tags: php, yii, cgridview

Is it possible to style CGridView based on data?
For example these two cases:

[image]

Or I have to use other options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can specify `css` class by data. Use [cssClassExpression](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridColumn#cssClassExpression-detail) option.

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'columns'=>array(
        // ...
        array(
            'name'=>'Delta',
            'value' => $data->value,
            'cssClassExpression' => '$data->delta > 0 ? "up" : "down"',
        ),
        // ...
    ),
));
```

Answer (score 1):

as clear from other answers that `cssClassExpression` can be used for this purpose. I think there would be many `if` statements so that you cant use inline `if` statements for cssClassExpression.
I would do it in this way.
1. First define a method in your model like

```
public function checkColour()
{
if('value'<10)
{
return 'green quarter'
}
if('value'>10)
{
return 'yellow half'
}
}
```

Basically this method is returning class names you have created and want to use for specific condition.
2. Then i would use it like

```
'columns'=>array(

        array(
            'name'=>'nozare',
            'cssClassExpression' => '$data->checkColour()'
        ),

    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using cssClassExpression

array(
    'name' => 'status',
    'value' => '$data->status0->title',
    'cssClassExpression' => call a function or do by expression,
),

By that you can set different class for different row and write corresponding css for that